# Getting error in DirectoryEntry using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldapconnection

I am using vb.net and the following code, but I am getting an error. I am new to vb.net and Active Directory, pls help me to solve this problem.

My code:

```
Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry()
    dirEntry.Path = "ldap://sunbs.in:389/CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=sunbs,DC=in"
    dirEntry.Username = "sunbs.in\sbsldap"
    dirEntry.Password = "sbs@123"
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher
    searcher.SearchRoot = dirEntry
```

When I debug the code the I get error in 2nd line. unknown error(0X80005000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an UPPERCASE `LDAP://` prefix for your `dirEntry.Path`:

```
Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry()

' use LDAP:// - not ldap://
dirEntry.Path = "LDAP://sunbs.in:389/CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=sunbs,DC=in" 

dirEntry.Username = "sunbs.in\sbsldap"
dirEntry.Password = "sbs@123"
Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher
searcher.SearchRoot = dirEntry
```

Comment: thank u so much for ur reply. how to check whether particular user exists in active directory

Comment: @sudha.s: that's a whole new question - please post a new question so we can answer ...